# Docker CMD - when should shell form be used?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

[Dockerfile - best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#cmd) says that

> CMD should almost always be used in the form of CMD ["executable",
>   "param1", "param2"…]

in which case shell form should be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shell form will invoke a command shell and do the usual command processing that the shell typically handles (like substitution of environment variables such as `$HOME`). The exec form doesn't do that.

That is closely related to the `SHELL` directive.

You can have multiple `SHELL` commands in the Dockerfile, but only one `CMD`. `CMD` is used to specify what the container should run when it starts. The `SHELL` directive will overwrite the default shell that is used by the shell-form of various commands (`RUN`, `CMD`, `ENTRYPOINT`).

Using this Dockerfile illustrates this better than I could explain it:

```
FROM python:3.6
RUN echo $PATH
SHELL ["/bin/bash" ,"-c"]
RUN echo $PATH
RUN ["echo", "$PATH"]
COPY run.sh /run.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/run.sh"]
```

Will result in this when running `docker build`:

```
$ docker build .

Sending build context to Docker daemon   5.12kB
Step 1/7 : FROM python:3.6
 ---> 5bf410ee7bb2
Step 2/7 : RUN echo $PATH
 ---> Running in 3a08d7c4450c
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
Removing intermediate container 3a08d7c4450c
 ---> 85b4da5d8e5d
Step 3/7 : SHELL ["/bin/bash" ,"-c"]
 ---> Running in da1b90ac14f2
Removing intermediate container da1b90ac14f2
 ---> ed747f0862a6
Step 4/7 : RUN echo $PATH
 ---> Running in 5c6a86e133ff
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
Removing intermediate container 5c6a86e133ff
 ---> 8ec42f23d390
Step 5/7 : RUN ["echo", "$PATH"]
 ---> Running in cc0650a6d8e8
$PATH
Removing intermediate container cc0650a6d8e8
 ---> 8b11432adb3a
Step 6/7 : COPY run.sh /run.sh
 ---> a168c58738e7
Step 7/7 : ENTRYPOINT ["/run.sh"]
 ---> Running in f9e28048d139
Removing intermediate container f9e28048d139
 ---> d20920ea562c
Successfully built d20920ea562c
```

Notice that when it ran the shell mode commands (using both the default shell and bash), $PATH was expanded, but not when run using exec mode.

Answer (score 3):

For `CMD`, you need shell form only if you need functionality that’s only provided in a shell — if your `CMD` includes environment variable references `$ARG`, multiple commands `a && b`, pipelines `| tee ...`, or redirections `2>&1`.  If you have an especially complex `CMD` like this it might be a better practice to move it to a shell script (that you can independently test outside of Docker) and have your default `CMD` just be to invoke the script.

`RUN` technically has the same considerations.  It’s very common to run multiple commands in the same `RUN` instruction, though, and this requires shell form.  Almost every `RUN` line I’ve ever seen uses the shell form.

`ENTRYPOINT` should *always* be the JSON-array form.  Remember that the entrypoint gets passed the command as arguments; if you use the shell form it effectively causes these arguments to be ignored.  Again, if you need to do complex things in your `ENTRYPOINT` (including `exec "$@"` to run the command), split it into a separate shell script and invoke it using JSON-array syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much never; if you need a shell command, you can just call a script with parenthesis format (`CMD ["bash", "myscript.sh"]`). The problem with shell form is that it breaks shutdown: https://hynek.me/articles/docker-signals/